# GitLab on Docker - How to set the external URL for GitLab

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I'm running GitLab on my machine by using the docker image.
On this machine I have several other services. 
So the machine Port 80 is already taken by something else.
So I did this port mapping **9088:80** ... now I face the problem that
Gitlab still thinks for external requests it runs on port 80 and also the runner 
stuck because:

So it uses http://psmonster/ instead of http://psmonster:9088/

```
Checking for jobs... received                       job=39 repo_url=http://psmonster/edi-tools/xsltestsuite.git runner=_z9oqvay
WARNING: Job failed: exit status 1                  duration=155.353588ms job=39 project=9 runner=_z9oqvay
WARNING: Failed to process runner                   builds=0 error=exit status 1 executor=shell runner=_z9oqvay
```

Does somebody know how to handle this?

Comment: Which port did you change...? there should be 3 publish option for the running command.

Comment: It was just by runnig:
      


    sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.example.com \
  --publish 30443:443 --publish 9088:80 --publish 30022:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest

Comment: There should be options like this.. `--publish 443:443 --publish 9080:80 --publish 22:22` which one did you change?

Comment: 9080 is taken by sonarqube ... but using 9080 will also cause this issue

Comment: It's a Mac? or Linux?

Comment: suse Linux but I think this doesn't matter

Comment: It does matter if it's a Mac code gonna be bit of different. Anyway you need to change your gitlab/config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check out

- https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#change-the-default-port-and-the-ssl-certificate-locations

you need to alter your config file.

---

Let us assume you start your gitlab container like this

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.example.com \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

this will create the config on your host machine in the folder `srv/gitlab/config`

Alter the config file from

```
external_url "https://gitlab.example.com:80"
```

to

```
external_url "https://psmonster:9088"
```

delete your container - since you do not have a use for the current one

```
docker rm -f gitlab
```

and start it again, however this time around the config files already exists and can be used by the container. Therefore it will use the proper port and you do not run into the port issue you described in your question. Please note the updated port definition

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.example.com \
  --publish 9088:9088 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

---

general docs on how to use the gitlab docker image can be found here

- https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/

Comment: Thanks that was really great!!

Comment: Can't we just restart the running container?

Comment: How would you do this, if you use docker-compose?

Comment: Use `sudo docker restart gitlab` instead of `docker rm -f gitlab`.